# Why are app files not available from second android user

Tags: android, multi-user

I created a 2nd user for the android device i am working on, and installed my app on the user's profile

however, the usual file tree for the app "files,cache,databases" doesnt seem to be available through this user.

How do I reach these files?

[image]

Comment: Are you using hard-coded paths to access files?

Comment: Please explain how you are viewing this file tree, and where you are looking for it.

Comment: adb shell , run-as com.mypackage.myapp , ls , what i see is "libs" folder only, instead of the usual "files" "cache" "databases"